# Show string formatting to a high score table

Tags: php, html-table, formatting, echo

I'm having troubles with my high score table.

Now it looks like:

```
Name            Score
----------------------
Luke            102
Tom             98
Baltazar78946   91
```

I want it to look like:

```
1. Luke           102
2. Tom            98
3. Baltazar78946  91
```

I have a mysql table from which i get the string

my echo looks like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
   {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['name'] . "\t" . $row['score'] . "\n";
   }
```

my mysql table has 3 columns ID(dont want to use it), name and score.

I'm new to PHP.

Can anyone help me with the code?

Edit:
So what am I doing wrong? It just shows a blank page

```
 <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        // Send variables for the MySQL database class.
        $rball1 = mysql_connect('myhostname', 'guest', 'psw') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('rball1') or die('Could not select database');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `scores` ORDER by `score` ASC LIMIT 10";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

        $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  

        echo "<table border='0'>";
            for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$i+1}.</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['score']}</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
            echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Just concate `$i+1` before your output.

Comment: Note: `mysql_*` is being deprecated. You should start looking into `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Echo'ing out with a while loop might be easier as well. `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){ echo $row['name'] . "\t" . $row['score'] . "\n"; }`

Answer (score 3):

Try putting it in a table.

```
echo "<table border='0'>";
for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
{

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$i+1}.</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['name']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['score']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You need `{$i+1}`. Otherwise, the table starts with 0.

Comment: +1 What @YUNOWORK said, and you need to close the last echo in the loop, as well as the very last echo. (edited it for you)

Comment: I think it would be bettor to post the whole code because it's not working and I dont understand PHP

Answer (score 0):

Tables are nice and working, but `<divs>` are better. In my opinion, tables are ugly and deprecated:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
{
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<div class='position'>{$i+1}.</div>";
    echo "<div class='name'>{$row['name']}</div>";
    echo "<div class='score'>{$row['score']}</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Its easier to style with `CSS`. FAR easier. You just have to set `position, name` and `score` with `display: inline-block` and you have to give them a width ofc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did:(I have added it a few more features too)

I dont know why but echo " "; isn't working for me

but echo ' '; works great

```
echo '<table style="width:60%;border:5px solid #cccccc;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:2px;">';
    echo '<col style="width:8%;" /> <col style="width:82%;" /> <col style="width:10%;" />';
    echo '<tr><td>#</td><td>NAME</td><td>DEATHS</td></tr>';
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++)
       {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo '<tr><td>' . $i . '</td><td>' . $row['name'] . '</td><td style="text-align:center;">' . $row['score'] . '</td></tr>';
       }
    echo '</table>';
```